# I want to recall readline . how to do that?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to recall this

```
rl.question("input your port do you want (about 0 - 65535) : ", function(portnumber)
```

after this:

```
if(netinfo > 6665){
    return console.log("Error stupid i say about 0 - 65535")
}

rl.question("input your port do you want (about 0 - 65535) : ", function(portnumber){
   if(netinfo > 6665){
     return console.log("Error stupid i say about 0 - 65535")
    } 

     netinfo = portnumber;

     const requestHandler = (request, response) => {  
      console.log(request.url)
      response.write('<b>welcome to groone simple http server :p </b>');
      response.end('ahahahahahah :)');
    }
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way i see is recursion:

```
(function restart(){
  rl.question("input your port do you want (about 0 - 65535) : ", function(portnumber){
    if(portnumber > 6665){
       console.log("Error stupid i say about 0 - 65535");
       return restart();
    }
    //...
  });
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an endless loop that will break when we receive the correct/expected answer.

Sample code:

```
var correctAnswer = false;
while(!correctAnswer){
    doStuff()
    if(0 < receivedAnswer && receivedAnswer  < 6665) correctAnswer = true;
}
```